How Can I Update My Room Version with Migrations?
I have a room database on my App. It's 3 files: Model, Database and DAO.
I'm add a new val to Model and I update my database version on Database file. And I get a crash.
@Database(entities = [Reminder::class], version = 1)
abstract class ReminderDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userReminderDao(): ReminderDAO

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: ReminderDatabase? = null

        val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE Reminder_2 (" +
                            "id INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                            "title TEXT, " +
                            "note TEXT, " +
                            "date TEXT, " +
                            "PRIMARY KEY(id))"
                )

                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Reminder_2 (id, title, note, date) SELECT id, title, note, date FROM Reminder")

                database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Reminder")

                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Reminder_2 RENAME TO Reminder")
            }
        }

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ReminderDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(ReminderDatabase::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ReminderDatabase::class.java,
                        "Reminder"
                    )
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build()
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE!!
        }
        

    }
}

I try the Migrations but I can't run it. When I open the app, in 2 seconds app get a crash. Please help me.

What is the stacktrace of the crash? What did you try exactly when you say "Migrations"?

For the migration to be invoked you need to change the version from 1 to 2. i.e. use @Database(entities = [Reminder::class], version = 2) instead of @Database(entities = [Reminder::class], version = 1)

I think that you just forgot to update your DB version number from 1 to 2. Everything seems ok but this.
As you gave your app a strategy to migrate from version 1 to version 2, it should work. I think this is just a matter of schema changed.
Your app just doesn't understand why the schema of version 1 has changed : which is normal because it is now version 2!
Change this section :
@Database(entities = [Reminder::class], version = 1)


hello You can write a code to update the database
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN password VARCHAR(255);

or
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN bookmarks VARCHAR(400000) NULL;

when the user logs in for the first time, and then after executing that code, update the database version and database creation code with the help of the interface and variables. And don't fill the new database fields as null.
